# Wireless 11ac usb adapter driver installation error

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, drivers, usb-drive, wlan

I decide to buy [Wireless 11AC USB adapter and download drivers,](https://archive.org/details/wireless-usb-adapter-11ac-rtl8811-rtl8812), after install I check by ip link or ifconfig and I didn't see wlan connection. When I tried download another drivers to install I got errors, I'm searching but I didn't find something that I need. I'm newbie in Kali Linux I just want to learn something new. If you have solutions or arch with drivers for my kali I'll be very appreciated! [image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My problem was related to model wifi adapter and specific kernel version of my distr kali linux, I found the same problem, here answer https://askubuntu.com/a/1067500

Comment: Feel free to quote and attribute the answer from AU so that this Answer is self-contained; thank you!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).